# Close all opened windows script

Tags: windows, powershell, batch-file, cmd, windows-7

Usually when i have too many opened windows like the below:

[image]

I select the 1st one then hold "Shift + Arrow down" to select all of them then click "End Task" to close all of the opened windows:

[image]

is there any CMD command to do the same at once, in which i'll run the script to do the same and close all the opened windows.

Comment: `taskkill /im cmd.exe /f`  ?

Comment: thank you @npocmaka but this command will only close CMD not all the opened applications

Comment: Use `tasklist` to get all tasks running and `taskkill` (in a loop) to terminate them...

Answer (score -1):

Yes, it is extremely trivial and far more powerfull:

```
ps skype, *word*, excel | kill
```

Call `ps` without any args to see all processes and their names.

Comment: You may want to note that you're talking about PowerShell here, and that you're using aliases for the cmdlets `Get-Process` and `Stop-Process`. The statement won't work in CMD.

Comment: I dont want to note that, obviously, I am not here to babysit. U probably didnt note a tag or u just feel lonely?